# VBA Run time Error 1004 "Sorry we could find file..". VBA loops through a folder compiling all the data into one excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a VBA code that loops through a Folder of the same files (diff data) and compile them into one excel sheet. However, there is an error:

"Run time error 1004: We can't find [file]"

```
    Sub LoopThroughFolderAllData()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
     Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
   Dim myPath As String
   Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog


Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
  .Title = "Select Folder with IQC Data"
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
 NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings



 'Target Path with Ending Extention
 MyFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")


Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & MyFile)
    Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
    With Worksheets("All Data")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 70))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("All Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
   Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

The error occurs on line:

```
Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: These lines, `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & MyFile)` and `Workbooks.Open (MyFile)` are confusing to me.  Why are you trying to open either the same file or a similar file twice?  First you call it with a path (directory) and a FileName, then the second time you just call it with the second variable which should be the File Name.  Is this your intention?  Does the workbook you want open before the error? It looks like it should open on `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & MyFile)` and you should not need that second line, or vice versa.

Comment: insert a _Stop_ command right after  _MyFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")_ then run the code.  it should pause at _Stop_  .... hover the mouse pointer over _MyFile_ and you should see a "tip" popup that shows the value of Myfile variable  ... do the same for _myPath_  ... are you seeing correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Amend the `Do While` code as follows:

```
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & MyFile)
    With Worksheets("All Data")
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rws, 70))
        Rng.Copy Wb.Worksheets("All Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 
        "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        wb.Close True
    End With
    MyFile = Dir()
Loop
```

I don't think you need this line

```
    myPath = myPath
```